# OSB business service processing the body variable without the xml tag

Tags: osb, oracle-fusion-middleware

How to pass the body without the tag to a Business service from proxy service route.. Just wanted the message to be routed to the JMS queue via business service. please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XQuery transformation which will return the text message (without `<soap:body>`) that you wish to send to the queue. Have a replace activity (with replace entire node) using this transformation in your routing.

Comment: Let me be more clear on the requirement. I have a JavaCallout service in the proxy service flow and I receive an out of it in a boy variable (which is with the
<soapenv:Body> tag).. I was not sure on how to pass this message to the JMS queue via routing as my requirement was have only the message. Whereas I am unable to send it to queue without the tag. 
@ Habin: Thank you for response. I will take and check on it.